# Designing tournament/matches database

Tags: sql, database, tournament

I'm trying to design simple data base that will present some kind of tournament. So I have table that present 'Matches' (it contains two team's ID's), I've also created table 'Round' (one round contains few  matches). And there's my question. I want to create 'something' (table/view/procedure/function) that will make possible for me to show ranking of my tournament after given (via argument or using 'where' in select instruction) id of round. For example, there are two teams, team A and team B. In first and second round team A won. So after i pass via something number '1' I want to get output:

```
Position | Team   | Points
:-----   | -----: | :----:
1        | Team A | 3
:-----   | -----: | :----:
2        | Team B | 0
```

What is the easiest way to achieve something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure I understand what the parameter you are passing in represents, but it sounds like you want to make a stored procedure.  And yes you are correct you could use the parameter that is passed in, in your where clause.

Comment: Parameter that is passed or used in 'where' clause is integer. If it's 1, the presented ranking is after 1 round. If it's 10, the presented ranking is after round 10. (Round is set of matches).  So what is the best way to do it? I think that table/view isn't that good and stored procedure is needed, but I'm not sure. I'm kind of new to the databases.

Comment: Could you show some more of your table design?  Won't you also need some tournament id?  How will you know what matches to look at?  Won't there be many teams in many different matches that have a round of 1?

Comment: Whole database is only for one tournament. Every match has his own ID ( every match contains winner's id). I have a table that has only 2 columns, Round's ID (it's not primary key) and Match's ID. I can post SQL query or UML of my database if it will make easier for you to help me.

Comment: Yes I think it would be helpful to post the UML, I am not quite seeing the full picture.